# One-to-one fail sugarOrm

Tags: android, one-to-one, sugarorm

I use sugarOrm and I want to save a place with an address object, when I save everything is fine but when I try to get address it's always null, the others data from the place are saved and I can get them but I don't know why I can't get my address object and its informations.

My code:

```
public class PlaceModel extends SugarRecord<PlaceModel> implements Parcelable {
    @Ignore
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<CategoryModel> categories = new ArrayList<CategoryModel>();
    @Ignore
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<MediaContentModel> medias = new ArrayList<MediaContentModel>();
    @Ignore
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<ReviewContentModel> reviews = new      A ArrayList<ReviewContentModel>();
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @Expose
    @Ignore
    private List<Double> location = new ArrayList<Double>();
    @Expose
    private String website;
    @Expose
    private AddressModel address;
    @SerializedName("global_score")
    @Expose
    private Integer globalScore;
    @SerializedName("popularity_score")
    @Expose
    private Integer popularityScore;
    @SerializedName("quality_score")
    @Expose
    private Integer qualityScore;
    @Expose
    @Ignore
    private Object prices;
    @Expose
    @Ignore
    private Object hours;
    @Expose
    @Ignore
    private Object phone;
    @Expose
    private String createdAt;
    @Expose
    private String updatedAt;
    @SerializedName("idObject")
    @Expose
    private String idPlace;

    private String listCategory;

    private String listMedias;

    private String listReviews;

    private String listLocation;

    public PlaceModel() {
    }
    // Setters, getters and stuff for parcelable
}
```

Address Model :

```
public class AddressModel extends SugarRecord<AddressModel> implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("street_address")
    @Expose
    private String streetAddress;
    @SerializedName("city")
    @Expose
    private String city;
    @SerializedName("state")
    @Expose
    @Ignore
    private Object state;
    @SerializedName("postal_code")
    private String postalCode;
    @SerializedName("country")
    @Expose
    private String country;

    public AddressModel(){
    }
    // Setters, getters and stuff for parcelable
}
```

When I save :

```
public void getPlaceDetails(String id)
    {
        RestClient client = RestClient.getInstance();
        propertiesReader = new PropertiesReader(mContext);
        Properties apiProperties = propertiesReader.loadPropertiesFile("api.properties");

        client.createRestClient(apiProperties.getProperty("APIUrl"), mContext);
        ApiManager apiManager = client.getApiManager();
        PlaceModel place = apiManager.getPlaceDetails(id);
        if (place != null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            place.setListCategory(gson.toJsonTree(place.getCategories()).getAsJsonArray().toString());
            place.setListMedias(gson.toJsonTree(place.getMedias()).getAsJsonArray().toString());
            place.setListReviews(gson.toJsonTree(place.getReviews()).getAsJsonArray().toString());
            place.setListLocation(gson.toJsonTree(place.getLocation()).getAsJsonArray().toString());
            places.add(place);
            place.save();
        }
    }
```

If I try to get address I get a `NullPointerException`.
I followed the doc of sugarOrm, Do I'm missing something ?

Thanks in advance to anyone.

Comment: Add your  complete code that you use to try and get the address. It may be an issue with your retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the save() method to save your AddressModel in PlaceModel with something like this :

```
if (address != null) {
    AdressModel model = new AdressModel(address);
    model.save;
    adress = model;
}
super.save();
```

It's not pretty but it's one of the solution, because right now, like written in the doc : *"One-to-one relationship doesn't work yet"*, so you have to find a work-around